# What do we say if the codomain was defined so that it doesn't fully cover the range of $f$?

Tags: functions

Take for example $f(x) = x^2$ and we define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \{1\}$.

What would we call this? As the range of $f$ is all non-negative real numbers yet the codomain is a subset of the range?

Comment: Before figuring out what it should be called, could you tell me what it should mean?

Comment: Do you mean what I'm trying to say? I realised that usually for functions we'd define $f$ to map to some codomain, that almost always has the range of $f$ as a subset (or equal to) but I've never seen the case when the codomain is a strict subset of the range

Comment: This is not possible. By definition, the range of a function must lie in the codomain.

Comment: No it's certainly not a function. The co-domain being a proper subset of the range  is somewhat of an oxymoron, which is why I ask what you want this to mean. What is $f(2)$ for example? As is, I'd say it's simply an ill-formed expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this has an answer: If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, a *mapping* $f:X \to Y$ is a subset $f$ of the Cartesian product $X \times Y$ with the following property:

> For every $x$ in $X$, there exists a *unique* $y$ in $Y$ such that $(x, y) \in f$.

A specification such as

> "Define $f:\mathbf{R}\to \{1\}$ by $f(x) = x^{2}$"

does not define a mapping: The set of ordered pairs $(x, x^{2})$ with $x$ real is not a subset of $\mathbf{R} \times \{1\}$.